# Git bash export function not recognized or without an effect

Tags: environment-variables, git-bash

I am using git-bash on windows, but unfortunately it seems I have a configuration issue. I am trying to use the export function to set environment variables, like so:

```
$ export php='/c/xampp/php/php.exe'

$ php -v
bash: php: command not found
```

This is also the case after a restart of git-bash.

Using the alias function works:

```
$ alias php='/c/xampp/php/php.exe'


$ php -v
PHP 7.4.7 (cli) (built: Jun  9 2020 13:36:15) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

I've also tried to register the environment variables directly in the `.bash_profile`-configuration-file, which I assume is the one located under `C:/Users/username`, but that does not work either.

As of now, I assume if haven't setup git correctly or made some stupid mistake. Any hint what I am missing would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Something you've read has given you the wrong idea regarding the purpose of environment variables. Env vars are inherited by new processes who interpret them in whatever manner makes sense for that program. The bash shell does not consult env vars, other than `$PATH`, when resolving external command names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are referenced with `$`, and you don’t need to `export` them unless you want them to become environment variables of spawned programs.

```
php=/c/xampp/php/php.exe
$php -v
```

You *should* continue using `alias` for this, though – that’s what it’s for! – or extend your `$PATH` instead:

```
PATH="$PATH:/c/xampp/php"
```